# PyTorch error when importing another model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I tried to import state-of-the-art EfficientNet model (pytorch implementation):

```
from efficientnet_pytorch import EfficientNet

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchvision.transforms import transforms as T
import torchvision
import torch.optim as optim

model = EfficientNet.from_pretrained('efficientnet-b0')
```

And I got this chain of errors when downloading model:

```
Downloading: "https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/releases/download/1.0/efficientnet-b0-355c32eb.pth" to /Users/telaust/.cache/torch/checkpoints/efficientnet-b0-355c32eb.pth
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1316                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1317                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1318             except OSError as err: # timeout error

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1228         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1229         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1230 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1274             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1275         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1276 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1223             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1224         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1225 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1015         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1016         self.send(msg)
   1017 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in send(self, data)
    955             if self.auto_open:
--> 956                 self.connect()
    957             else:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in connect(self)
   1383 
-> 1384             super().connect()
   1385 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in connect(self)
    927         self.sock = self._create_connection(
--> 928             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
    929         self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    726     if err is not None:
--> 727         raise err
    728     else:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    715                 sock.bind(source_address)
--> 716             sock.connect(sa)
    717             # Break explicitly a reference cycle

TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5e9bdf5b3e02> in <module>
----> 1 model = EfficientNet.from_pretrained('efficientnet-b0')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/efficientnet_pytorch/model.py in from_pretrained(cls, model_name, advprop, num_classes, in_channels)
    209     def from_pretrained(cls, model_name, advprop=False, num_classes=1000, in_channels=3):
    210         model = cls.from_name(model_name, override_params={'num_classes': num_classes})
--> 211         load_pretrained_weights(model, model_name, load_fc=(num_classes == 1000), advprop=advprop)
    212         if in_channels != 3:
    213             Conv2d = get_same_padding_conv2d(image_size = model._global_params.image_size)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/efficientnet_pytorch/utils.py in load_pretrained_weights(model, model_name, load_fc, advprop)
    325     # AutoAugment or Advprop (different preprocessing)
    326     url_map_ = url_map_advprop if advprop else url_map
--> 327     state_dict = model_zoo.load_url(url_map_[model_name])
    328     if load_fc:
    329         model.load_state_dict(state_dict)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/hub.py in load_state_dict_from_url(url, model_dir, map_location, progress, check_hash)
    490         sys.stderr.write('Downloading: "{}" to {}\n'.format(url, cached_file))
    491         hash_prefix = HASH_REGEX.search(filename).group(1) if check_hash else None
--> 492         download_url_to_file(url, cached_file, hash_prefix, progress=progress)
    493 
    494     # Note: extractall() defaults to overwrite file if exists. No need to clean up beforehand.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/hub.py in download_url_to_file(url, dst, hash_prefix, progress)
    389     # We use a different API for python2 since urllib(2) doesn't recognize the CA
    390     # certificates in older Python
--> 391     u = urlopen(url)
    392     meta = u.info()
    393     if hasattr(meta, 'getheaders'):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    523             req = meth(req)
    524 
--> 525         response = self._open(req, data)
    526 
    527         # post-process response

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    541         protocol = req.type
    542         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
--> 543                                   '_open', req)
    544         if result:
    545             return result

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in https_open(self, req)
   1358         def https_open(self, req):
   1359             return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
-> 1360                 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
   1361 
   1362         https_request = AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1317                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1318             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1319                 raise URLError(err)
   1320             r = h.getresponse()
   1321         except:

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 60] Operation timed out>
```

I'm so confused about this error, so I see that problem is related to URL, but I can't solve it. Before that I installed this model through pip:

```
pip3 install efficientnet_pytorch
```

How can I fix this error? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you find the link for the model you're downloading in the code? My guess is that the link is either temporarily down (more likely) or incorrect. Once you find the link enter it into your browser to see if it works that way.

Comment: So, this link: https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch It seems to me that everything is fine with the link

Comment: Try updating effecientnet with `pip install --upgrade efficientnet-pytorch
`

Comment: Have you checked you internet connection also. Its working fine for me